# Function not returning to caller after using socket()

Tags: c, sockets, server, client

As shown in my following code. I have a function to create a socket in my server application. My code compiles fine and all; however, the function (named createSocket) will not finish. Hence, my program is stuck waiting forever when I run my program. I know this because, the fprinf function which is the next statement after my createSocket function never prints out.

I've added a printf statement as my last statement of my createSocket function. And it does print! But it doesn't return to the caller (which is main).

```
struct addrinfo serverInfo, *pToResult;
struct sockaddr_storage client_addr;
int serverfd, connectfd;

void createSocket(char**);
void bindSocketToPort(void);
void startListenAndAccept(void);
void recvAndSend(void);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     createSocket(argv);
     fprintf(stdout, "create socket function done");
     bindSocketToPort();
     startListenAndAccept();
     recvAndSend();
     return 0;
}

#define serv pToResult
void createSocket(char** argv)
{
     memset(&serverInfo, 0, sizeof serverInfo);
     serverInfo.ai_family = PF_INET;
     serverInfo.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

     if(getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", argv[1], &serverInfo, &serv) != 0)
     {
           perror("getaddrinfo error");
           exit(1);
     }

     if( (serverfd = socket(serv->ai_family, serv->ai_socktype, serv->ai_protocol) ) == -1)
     {
           perror("socket error");
           exit(1);
     }
     puts("william");
     return;
}
```

After compiling with gcc, and passing in 65000 as an argument to my program. The results are, only "william" printed out on the console, and then I am kept waiting (the program is still running).

Comment: A proper [mcve] please. What are `serverInfo` and `serv`? Did you smash the stack or something?

Comment: serverInfo contains information about my server and is of type struct addrinfo. @AnttiHaapala

Comment: serv is a pointer to serverInfo. @AnttiHaapala

Comment: Append a `\n` character to the end of the strings in your your print statements. That will force the output to flush to the screen more reliably.  My psychic powers suggest your code is getting further ahead that you think - but stdout is buffered.

Comment: I just appened \n to my print statements. All it did was it went to a new line. @selbie

Comment: @user7529140 the newline must be placed at the **end** of the message, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The results are, only "william" printed out on the console

just replace

> ```
> fprintf(stdout, "create socket function done");
> ```

by

```
fprintf(stdout, "create socket function done\n");
```

or

```
puts("create socket function done");
```

to flush the output thank to the newline

Of course that supposes you reach that *printf*, that means  *bindSocketToPort* and *startListenAndAccept* and *recvAndSend* return

> passing in 65000 as an argument to my program

note you do not use the argument(s)

---

Example defining *bindSocketToPort* and *startListenAndAccept* and *recvAndSend* with an empty body :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

struct addrinfo serverInfo, *pToResult;
struct sockaddr_storage client_addr;
int serverfd, connectfd;

void createSocket(char**);
void bindSocketToPort(void) {}
void startListenAndAccept(void){}
void recvAndSend(void){}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     createSocket(argv);
     fprintf(stdout, "create socket function done\n");
     bindSocketToPort();
     startListenAndAccept();
     recvAndSend();
     return 0;
}

#define serv pToResult
void createSocket(char** argv)
{
     memset(&serverInfo, 0, sizeof serverInfo);
     serverInfo.ai_family = PF_INET;
     serverInfo.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

     if(getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", argv[1], &serverInfo, &serv) != 0)
     {
           perror("getaddrinfo error");
           exit(1);
     }

     if( (serverfd = socket(serv->ai_family, serv->ai_socktype, serv->ai_protocol) ) == -1)
     {
           perror("socket error");
           exit(1);
     }
     puts("william");
     return;
}
```

Compilation and execution

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra s.c
s.c: In function ‘main’:
s.c:17:14: warning: unused parameter ‘argc’ [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
              ^~~~
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
william
create socket function done
```

Comment: the fprinf(stdout, "create socket function done"); statement in my program is not even getting printed out. I only have "william" as output. @bruno

Comment: @user7529140 did you added the '\n' ?

Comment: @user7529140 start your program in a debugger to check if _bindSocketToPort_ and _startListenAndAccept_ and _recvAndSend_ return

Comment: ohh hold on a second, I think I am getting something. @bruno

Comment: omg thank you so much! It works!!!! Can you explain to me what flushing out the output mean? @bruno

Comment: @user7529140 _flush_ means output the buffered characters not yet output. WHen you output a newline that forces a flush

Comment: i already have functions bindSocketToPort, startListenAndAccept... all writen. I  just didn't included it.

Comment: @user7529140 I just defined them empty to be able to compile and execute

Comment: where can I find more information on flushing out the output? again thank you so much bruno @bruno

Comment: @user7529140 again to write a newline (\n) force the flush, you can also use _fflush_ (`int fflush(FILE *stream);`)  in case you do not want to produce a newline

Comment: also, when you typed in my fprintf statement. You are missing an ending "